# Is there a Fortran compiler/emulator for iOS?

Tags: ios

Has anyone come across a Fortran 77 emulator or compiler for iOS devices?

Comment: Why would you *want* one?

Comment: @FakeName Numeric and machine learning libraries, as a few examples.

Answer (score 4):

It can be accomplished using the Dragonegg plugin for GCC (frontend), a generic LLVM installation (backend), and the Apple linker.  I have been able to successfully build and run a 64-bit Fortran application on iOS 8.1 built on Mac OS X 10.10 using GCC 4.8 and LLVM 3.5.  The process is not very straightforward and requires a number of hacks and some scripting, but the high-level steps are:

1. Install GCC 4.8 from HPC for Mac OS X into /usr/local
2. Install Clang/LLVM 3.5 from llvm.org into /usr/local
3. Download the Dragonegg source code from the LLVM website
4. Build dragonegg.so and install it to /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/4.8.1/plugin
5. Download GCC 4.8.1 sources
6. Build libgfortran for arm64 using a combination of Apple clang for C/C++, Dragonegg for Fortran, and some wrapper scripts to piece together the compilers
7. Install libgfortran.dylib and libgfortran.3.dylib to /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/usr/lib
8. Install libgfortran.3.dylib on the iPhone under /usr/local/lib

Now if you got this far, compile a Fortran source file into an iOS binary using:

1. gfortran -O3 -fplugin=dragonegg -fplugin-arg-dragonegg-llvm-codegen-optimize=3 -fplugin-arg-dragonegg-emit-ir -S -o main.s main.f
2. llc -mtriple arm64-apple-darwin -filetype=obj -o main.o main.s
3. ld -arch arm64 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk -lSystem -lgfortran main.o -o main

Precompiled binaries for Dragonegg and libgfortran can be found here: http://download.zeroepoch.com/gfortran-ios/gfortran-ios.tar.bz2

**UPDATE: The precompiled binaries archive now contains fat libraries (armv7s, arm64) and some bug fixes to the wrapper scripts.**

Comment: I found this link useful for building dragonegg.so, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26009274/dragonegg-on-mac-os-x-issues

Comment: FYI, I was able to compile all of the Fortran benchmarks from SPEC FP for iOS using this method.

Comment: Could you be more specific with your 6th step, build libgfortran for arm64?
I'm trying to find a way to built it but I did not succeed.

Comment: I had to get this work done quickly so I didn't take notes, but I didn't want to lose the binaries.  I just remember I had to hack the source quite a bit.  The majority of the trouble was setting the fortran compiler to my wrapper script since gfortran has some fortran libraries inside.

Comment: Thank you very much for the idea. It works. Regarding the 8th step, I was not able to copy the dylib into the proposed location. I had to change the location like this: `install_name_tool -id @executable_path/../Frameworks/libgfortran.3.dylib libgfortran.3.dylib`. In XCode a Copy build step is needed. Copy libgfortran.3.dylib and set the destination to _Executables_.

Comment: I am not able to use _libgfortran.3.dylib_ on the iOS device: `test4.app/libgfortran.3.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture`. Any ideas?

Comment: timomeinen, I only have pre-built binaries for armv7s and arm64.  If you built them yourself you will need both compiled libraries.  If you're making a real app you might even need armv7 as well.  You combine them with lipo.  I was only using this on a jailbroken device at the SSH prompt.

Comment: Tried to compile [ARPACK](http://www.caam.rice.edu/software/ARPACK/) using your pre-built binaries and linker exits with error: `Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: "etime", referenced from: second in second.o`. Could you, please point me to the right direction to where should I look for the problem?

Comment: Andriy, It sounds like the ARPACK library or something related is using a function that doesn't exist on iOS called "etime".  I've never seen that function before so I'm not sure what it does.  You might want to look at rewriting that code to use gettimeofday or something similar.

Comment: Great work Eric, would you be able to put the fat libs and wrappers for arm64 precompiled binary of libgfortran on some FTP or Git again ? (the link is dead). Also I am trying to run fortran code on iOS device and put it to App Store - in this case it is not really possible to do step 8. Any idea how to overcome this ? (it seems almost impossible to create a static library of fortran on arm64)

Comment: @Ammo, That link was to a file previously on a web server of mine.  Since I haven't use this work in a long time I forgot about it and don't have a backup anymore.  If someone has has the time and initiative it would be great if they got some scripts pushed to a github repo to build this library.  I don't even have a mac anymore to test if a script worked so I wouldn't be much help on that either.  Maybe you could explore using Linux to create an LLVM bytecode file and the create an object file and archive from that on a mac.

Comment: I'm here trying to get HTDP (https://www.ngs.noaa.gov/TOOLS/Htdp/Htdp.shtml) compiling on iOS. Question on the step 2. would llvm/clang already be on there if I have Xcode installed?

Comment: @matrixugly, It would already be included with Xcode.  I don't remember why I needed the vanilla LLVM.  Maybe it was missing some feature.

Comment: @Eric Thanks - You wouldn't still happen still have those precompiled versions of Dragonegg and libgfortran (link is dead from above)? I'm having a heck of a time trying to get those compiled from source.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps it's best done with a pre-compiler translating Fortran to C (and integrate that into Xcode as a separate build step). One such tool is e.g. http://www.greatmigrations.com/tools_gmFortran.aspx

Maybe one can also have a look at the gnu fortran compiler, as far as I remember it also started out as a precompiler translating Fortran to C. http://gcc.gnu.org/fortran/